# Joining splitted data series into a graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I've used the following code to split data by IDs [-1,1,2...10], each ID has multiple values. For example

> [-1,-1,-1,-1] [500,520,620,785] | [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] [800,754,620,...] ...

```
def split_by_ids(data: np.array, ids: np.array):
    splits = []  # result storage
    # get unique indicies with their counts from ids array
    elems, counts = np.unique(ids, return_counts=True)
    # go through each index and its count
    for index, count in zip(elems, counts):
        # create array of same index and grab corresponding values from data
        splits.append((np.repeat(index, count), data[ids == index]))

    return splits

#arr is an array with all the values contained on a text file 
IDs= arr[0]
X= arr[1]
Y= arr[2]

A = split_by_ids(X, IDs)
B = split_by_ids(Y, IDs)
    for i in range(0,10):
      plt.plot(A[i][1], B[i][1], label='Series '+str(i-1))

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Now, when plotting the data using matplotlib I obtain a graph where data series are not joined (as it should be), Is there a way to connect each list so that it appears as a "single line with different colors" when plotted.

[What It's plotting right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZLGG.png)

[Plot without splitting values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJta9.png)

Comment: does `plt.margins(x=0, y=0)` just below `plt.plot(A[i][1], B[i][1], label='Series '+str(i-1))` help?

Comment: @DavidErickson nope, same thing :(

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. You need to decide how you want `matplotlib` to connect disparate sets of data and program accordingly. Not sure anyone else can answer that for you. If you don't need the data to be separated, then don't call `split_by_ids`.

Comment: E.g. should the lines between datasets be drawn in dark grey? In the colour of the previous dataset or the next dataset? Whatever you choose, you'll need to call `plot` to plot those additional connecting lines.

Comment: @Myridium Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for. I know what is plotted is the real data, but I would like to connect each dataset with for example the previous color or black or whatever just to be aesthetically more pleasing and don't see gaps in between

Comment: I can draw a black graph without splitting and then draw on top the splitted by ids dataset, I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this

Comment: @Yassin when you're representing data on a graph you should not make any aesthetic choices that confound the interpretation of the graph. E.g. I think plotting a dark grey line is okay, since it could not be confused as being a part of either dataset on the sides. But I think plotting in the same colour as one of the adjacent datasets is bad and I would not encourage it.

Comment: @Yassin can you please make this a Minimum Working example? You need to `import numpy as np`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and also instantiate an example `arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice job you did, yes, it is possible, `Draw the whole curve first`:

```
plt.plot(X, Y, label='Base')
```

then draw over the other curves, that will cover the base one.

the final code would be:

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def split_by_ids(data: np.array, ids: np.array):
    splits = []  # result storage
    # get unique indicies with their counts from ids array
    elems, counts = np.unique(ids, return_counts=True)
    # go through each index and its count
    for index, count in zip(elems, counts):
        # create array of same index and grab corresponding values from data
        splits.append((np.repeat(index, count), data[ids == index]))

    return splits

#arr is an array with all the values contained on a text file
IDs= arr[0]
X= arr[1]
Y= arr[2]

plt.plot(X, Y, label='Base') ########### Draw all first with a base line

A = split_by_ids(X, IDs)
B = split_by_ids(Y, IDs)
for i in range(0,10):
      plt.plot(A[i][1], B[i][1], label='Series '+str(i-1))

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```